# 2 statements printed on same line in terminal

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "Hello World" + "!!";
        System.out.print(message.replace("!!", "**"));
        System.out.print(message);
    }
}
```

I want to get the printed statements to appear on different lines in the terminal. I get this instead:

```
Hello World**Hello World!!
```

Comment: Use `println` instead of `print` if you want a line break after the output.

Comment: Use println or add a newline?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-System-out-println-and-System-out-print-in-Java?share=1

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing everything on a single line is because you're calling [`print()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(java.lang.String)) instead of [`println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String)).

You could print two lines by making two separate calls to `println()`, like this:

```
String message = "Hello World!!";
System.out.println(message.replace("!!", "**"));
System.out.println(message);
```

or you could make a single call, but combine the values with a line separator, like this:

```
String message = "Hello World!!";
System.out.print(message.replace("!!", "**") + System.lineSeparator() + message);
```